# Что означают запятые в функцях cin и cout?

Tags: c++, консоль, компилятор, операторы

Сегодня я случайно написал в `cin` следующее:

```
int h, w, r, c;
cin >> h, w, r, c;
```

Происходил Runtime Error. Я долго не мог разобраться в чем дело. Когда разобрался, для интереса решил сделать тоже самое в `cout`.

```
cout << h, w, r, c;
```

При любых значениях он всегда выводит `h`.

Вопрос: действительно ли он выводит первую переменную, и если да, почему не возникает ошибки компиляции? И почему тогда возникает Runtime в `cin`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cout << h, w, r, c;
```

это выражение (см. [оператор запятая](http://www.c-cpp.ru/books/operator-zapyataya)), которое поочередно выполняет выражения

```
cout << h
w
r
c
```

и возвращает значение последнего - `с`...

Ошибка *времени выполнения* в случае с `cin` может происходить по разным причинам - для этого нужно посмотреть код. Например, вы считаете, что введены 4 целых числа, а на самом три остаются в буфере и мешают последующему вводу... Или слет на использовании неинициализированных переменных... Или... - словом, без реального кода говорить о чем-то - просто гадание...

Comment: Спасибо, а `cin` объяснимо?

Comment: См. вторую часть ответа.

Comment: @VerNicksaysReinstateMonica https://ideone.com/aSPpDL в общем минимальный пример бы.

Comment: Все, я понял, просто сильно туплю. Я потом делю на нулевые переменные ‍♀️